# Typescript: Unexpected token `interface' w/ React Js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsconfig

1. After I npm run dev on local host I get the error:
   x Unexpected token `interface`. Expected this, import, async, function, [ for array literal, { for object literal, @ for decorator, function, class, null, true, false, number, bigint, string,
   | regexp, ` for template literal, (, or an identifier

This is a snippet of the code:

```
interface SidebarProps {
      initialSelectedIcon: string
    }
    
    function Sidebar({ initialSelectedIcon }: SidebarProps) {
      const [selected, setSelected] = useState<String>(initialSelectedIcon)
      const { currentAccount, currentUser } = useContext(TwitterContext)
      const router = useRouter()
```

2. There are no problems in the Terminal
3. I converted a bunch of js files to tsx
4. Here is my tsconfig.json

   ```
       {
        "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "incremental": true
      },
       "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", 
       "pages/components/2_Sidebar.tsx"],
       "exclude": ["node_modules"]
    }
   ```
5. Below is my Package.json

   ```
      "scripts": {
        "build": "rimraf ./build && tsc",
        "dev": "nodemon",
        "start": "npm run build && node build/index.tsx"
      },
      "keywords": [
        "sanity"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "@sanity/base": "^2.29.5",
        "@sanity/core": "^2.29.5",
        "@sanity/default-layout": "^2.29.5",
        "@sanity/default-login": "^2.29.5",
        "@sanity/desk-tool": "^2.29.5",
        "@sanity/eslint-config-studio": "^2.0.0",
        "@sanity/vision": "^2.29.5",
        "eslint": "^8.6.0",
        "prop-types": "^15.7",
        "react": "^17.0",
        "react-dom": "^17.0",
        "styled-components": "^5.2.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^17.0.21",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
        "rimraf": "^3.0.0",
        "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
        "typescript": "^4.6.2"
      }
    }
   ```
6. I think there might be a problem with the tsconfig.json or package.json

Comment: use lower case `interface`

Comment: *Edit* interface is lowercase

Comment: @dustycar17 Have solved this issue? I have same error after running npm run dev.